# AngularJS load table after filter is applied

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I want to do a search button, that will allow the user to enter in some data and then load a table containing the data they searched for.  I have been able to add a table and search the table, but I want the table to not be visible until the user enters in their search in an input and then clicks a button.  I'm not sure how to do this. I made a plnkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/qrVQ57iVBLV8AHn55I6P?p=preview

I have the following table:

```
<div>
<div>Lookup Results</div>
<div><input type="text" id="searchText" name="searchText" ng-model="query" /></div>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Acc. ID</td>
            <td>Acc. Name</td>
            <td>Acc Address</td>
            <td>City</td>
            <td>Zip</td>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td>Parent Name</td>
            <td>Account Type</td>
            <td>Account Status</td>
            <td>Credit Term</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="result in vm.results | filter:query ">
            <td>{{ result.accountId }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.accountName }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.address }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.city }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.state }}</td>
            <td>{{ reuslt.zip }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.phone }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.parentName }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.accountType }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.accountStatus }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.accountStatus }}</td>
            <td>{{ result.creditTerm }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and here is my controller.

```
(function () {

'use strict';

angular
  .module('crm.ma')
  .controller('LookUpCtrl', LookUpCtrl);

function LookUpCtrl() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.results = [
        {
            accountId: 1,
            accountName: 'some name',
            address: '201 some st',
            city: 'Columbus',
            state: 'OH',
            zip: 'zip',
            phone: '899-629-7645',
            parentName: 'Parent 1',
            accountType: 'Type 1',
            accountStatus: 'Status 1',
            creditTerm: 'Term 1'
        },
        {
            accountId: 2,
            accountName: 'house home',
            address: '2963 this st',
            city: 'Columbus',
            state: 'OH',
            zip: 'zip',
            phone: '899-627-7592',
            parentName: 'Parent 2',
            accountType: 'Type 2',
            accountStatus: 'Status 2',
            creditTerm: 'Term 2'
        }
    ];


}
}());
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?  If you can even point me in the direction of a tutorial that would be great help.

Comment: That plunker is worthless , all the assets point at `bower_components` that don't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put an `ng-if` on the table so table won't exist without any query value

```
<table ng-if="query">
```